# require и include

Tags: require, include, php

Здравствуйте товарищи! Понимаю, что вопрос повторяется, но он ещё актуален!

На официальном ресурсе **PHP** не говорится в описании функции **require**, что она включает указанные файлы ДО начала работы обработчика, наоборот между **require** и **include** как сообщается нет существенной разницы.

Раньше, помню, как говорилось о том, что **require** включает файлы ДО начала работы обработчика не обращая внимания на положение этой функции и выполнится она по условию, или нет. Использовалась соответственно для включения нужных файлов, но была быстрее **include** т.к. выполняла свою работу ДО начала работы обработчика.

А **include** хорош тем, что может динамически подключать файлы, например в цикле, и при отсутствии файла не остановит работу сценария, а лишь вызовет предупреждение.

Собственно вопрос : Я как достаточно серьёзный PHP программист, нуждаюсь в справке по этим функциям, мне нужно ускорить работу своих сценариев, **расскажите об этих функциях, как они работают в PHP5?**

Вот один из экспериментов :

```
<?php
echo (function_exists('_tools_configurations')) ? 'ok': 'no';
require('./system/tools/_/_tools_configurations/_tools_configurations.php');
?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Практика показывает, что require работает быстрее
но он собирает подключаемые файлы в начале работы скрипта, а include подключает по ходу
из этой логики вытекает, что если у вас есть условия для подключения файлов, то используйте include,
если нет условий - то require
ну и внешне отличается показом сообщений об ошибках (если файл не доступен)
require более строг к этому делу.

(c) какой-то старый сайт, на котором раньше ползал

Comment: Хорошо, код который я выложил, говорит о том, что require выполнится после проверки существования функции, которая  будет в подключаемом файле. В ответ я получил "no".

Comment: Если объяснять на пальцах и в грубых выражениях, то получается примерно следующее:
`include` добавляет код и тут же исполняет, в том время как `require` сначала вставит код (до начала исполнения скрипта), а выполнит его только когда до него дойдет. Вывод: в Вашем коде на момент исполнения `echo` функция не определена.

Comment: Вот за разъяснение спасибо!

Comment: Хотя, ходят слухи и подтверждаются тестами, что с PHP5 между конструкциями `include` и `require` только одно отличие - первая выдает только "Warning", а вторая еще и "Fatal error". А значит, `require` - специальное решение для любителей `die()` в теле функции.